# How to make class that spawns objects of same class

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

I'm trying to make a `particle` class that has the ability to spawn other particles, but am tying myself in knots!

So far I created a `spawner` class that holds a vector of particles. I figured the `particle` class would need to able to "see" the spawner in order to add new particles to this vector, so inside `particle` I created a pointer back to this spawner. Then my hope was that the `particle::spawn()` function would create a new particle and add it to the vector, but it's thowing an error ("Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)").

Why is this code not working? Is there some far simpler way of achieving this that I'm missing?

Note - I'm actually using a vector of *pointers* to particles inside `spawner` because I eventually want to create a sub-class (e.g. `particle_sub1`) with it's own `spawn()` and `test()` functions that can be accessed via polymorphism.

Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

// forward declare particle class
class particle;

// --------------------------------
// spawner class
class spawner {
public:
    // vector of pointers to particles
    vector<particle*> particle_ptr_vec;

    spawner() {};
};

// --------------------------------
// particle class
class particle {
public:
    // pointer back to spawner object
    static spawner* spawner_ptr;

    particle() {};
    void set_ptr(spawner &x) {spawner_ptr = &x;}
    virtual void spawn();
    virtual void test() {cout << "pass test\n";}

};

// initialise static variable
spawner* particle::spawner_ptr;

// spawn new particle
void particle::spawn() {
    particle x;
    spawner_ptr->particle_ptr_vec.push_back(&x);
    cout << "spawn particle\n";
}

// --------------------------------
// main funciton
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    // create spawner
    spawner s;

    // create first particle and define pointer back to spawner
    particle z;
    s.particle_ptr_vec.push_back(&z);
    s.particle_ptr_vec[0]->set_ptr(s);

    // spawn new particle
    s.particle_ptr_vec[0]->spawn();

    // check that two particles exist
    cout << "number of particles: " << s.particle_ptr_vec.size() << "\n";

    // test that worked
    s.particle_ptr_vec[0]->test();  // this test passes
    s.particle_ptr_vec[1]->test();  // this test throws the error
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the problem

```
// spawn new particle
void particle::spawn() {
    particle x;
    spawner_ptr->particle_ptr_vec.push_back(&x);
    cout << "spawn particle\n";
}
```

You are saving on your vector a pointer to an object that is destroyed when you exit the method.

One answer is dynamic allocation of objects, i.e. creating objects that have indefinite lifetimes, so you can control when they are destroyed.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. How can I avoid this? Do I need `spawner` to contain the actual particles as well as pointers to particles so they are not destroyed? Thanks again!

Comment: The most basic method is to use `new`. I.e. `spawner_ptr->particle_ptr_vec.push_back(new particle);`. But really this is a huge topic with lots of complexitites and alternative ways of doing things. You really need a good book.

Comment: @bobverity There's not much point storing objects and pointers, if you have the object you can always get a pointer to it. But storing objects only is an alternative depending on exactly what you are trying to achieve. See maxim's answer.

Comment: My reason for using pointers was that I want to use function polymorphism, for example a `particle_sub1` class that has its own `spawn()` function, but that can still be stored in the `particle_ptr_vec`. I found that if I make `particle_ptr_vec` a vector of particles rather than pointers to particles then I always get the base class behaviour. Your `new particle` suggestion seems to have fixed it, but I'm wary of memory leaks as I'm not sure where/how to destroy this object.

Comment: @bobverity Well that is exactly the problem. One simple solution (may not be appropriate for you) is to use unqiue_ptr. vector<unqiue_ptr<particle>> particle_ptr_vec. Now your vector owns the pointers and will delete them. The problem is there can only be one owner so you have to be careful copying unque_ptr because doing so transfers ownership. As I said it's a big topic and there are many possible approaches.

Comment: Thanks for the help john, I think your dynamic allocation method is the best solution to the immediate problem. I'll also take your advice and read a good book to try and avoid being in this situation, as I think there must be something I'm doind wrong structurary to have ended up here. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Store particles by value to solve your problem: `vector<particle> particle_ptr_vec;`. And then `spawner_ptr->particle_ptr_vec.push_back({});`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to solve a problem with object orientation, which is much more suited to a functional style. This gets you into trouble, because your objects are now managing data of other particles instead of just their own. This is in direct opposition of the encapsulation principle used in OOP.

I would suggest doing something like this:

```
auto particles = std::vector<particle>{};

//initialize some values into particles...

//define a new particle list or the for each syntax does not work
auto new_particles = std::vector<particle>{};

for (auto&& current : particles)
    if (current.needs_to_spawn_new_particles())
        for (auto&& new_particle : current.new_particles())
            new_particles.emplace_back(new_particle);

//update particles with new_particles
```

This even leaves you room to expand the functionality:

```
for (auto&& current : particles) {
    current.update();
    if (current.needs_to_spawn_new_particles())
        for (auto&& new_particle : current.new_particles())
            new_particles.emplace_back(new_particle);
    else if (!current.needs_to_be_destroyed())
            new_particles.emplace_back(current);
}
```

Which now gives you all particles in the `new_particles` vector (with the destroyed one removed).